# How to open an SQLite database readonly in Julia?

Tags: sqlite, julia

I'd like to read my Safari history database from a Julia script (Mac OS X).

I have a command line script that works:

```
sqlite3 -readonly ~/Library/Safari/History.db 'SELECT v.title, i.url FROM history_items i, history_visits v WHERE i.url LIKE "%en.wikipedia.org%" AND i.id=v.history_item AND v.title LIKE "%- Wikipedia%" GROUP BY v.title ORDER BY v.visit_time'
```

... but trying it in Julia (in Juno / Atom) gives me a permission error

```
db = SQLite.DB("/Users/grimxn/Library/Safari/History.db")
sql = """
    SELECT v.title, i.url, v.visit_time
    FROM history_items i, history_visits v
    WHERE i.url LIKE "%en.wikipedia.org%"
        AND i.id=v.history_item
        AND v.title LIKE "%- Wikipedia%"
    GROUP BY v.title
    ORDER BY v.visit_time
"""
result = DBInterface.execute(db, sql) |> DataFrame
(rows, cols) = size(result)
println("Result has $(rows) rows")
println("Earliest: $(result[1,1])")
println("Latest: $(result[rows,1])")
```

> ERROR: LoadError: SQLite.SQLiteException("unable to open database file")

Now, when I copy the database to my home directory, and swap

```
db = SQLite.DB("/Users/grimxn/Library/Safari/History.db")
```

to

```
db = SQLite.DB("/Users/grimxn/History.db")
```

everything works, so I *guess* it is that the Julia / Juno process has only got read permissions, but is accessing the db read/write.

How do I attach to the database as readonly in Julia?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, use a URI connection string: `file:foo.db?mode=ro`.

This is documented [in the SQLite manual](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

Practically, it appears the current version of the SQLite.jl package does not support URIs, and neither does it support flags that could be passed along to `sqlite3_open_v2()`.

Leaving this answer for reference just in case the Julia package fixes this some day.

Answer (score 2):

Jaen's answer was correct, and also correctly predicted that the `mode=ro` flag would be supported. [It is now supported](https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/SQLite.jl/issues/314), and so the following will work (and does as of today):

```
julia> using SQLite

julia> db = SQLite.DB("file:/path/to/db.sqlite?mode=ro")
SQLite.DB("file:/path/to/db.sqlite?mode=ro")
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up, and the assignation in your answer works without error, however actually *executing* still causes an error, at least here. Using a fresh installation of 1.8.5.